# Chrome extension - For facebook to block 'seen at' in Messages

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension

I was going through a few Chrome extensions that claim to disable the 'Seen At' feature of facebook messages.

[image: Seen at]
<sub>(source: [thetecnica.com](http://thetecnica.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Capture.png))</sub>

How can this be achieved from a Chrome extension considering the fact that the extension gets executed in its own isolated world?

I understand that this can be achieved using the Graph API but was wondering how this works with just UI?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Disable "seen" from extension, you have to Block just One URL: https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php 
So after that read status will be blocked.

you have to run script on background:

```
"background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
}
```

And the background.js files would be following:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
  return {
    cancel: true
  }
}, { urls: ['*://*.facebook.com/*change_read_status.php*'] }, ['blocking'])
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use adblock or adblock plus addon or extensions for your 
browser(or any other extension which can block script file)
suppose if you will use adblock
then go to adblock icon 
filter preferences
custom filter ->add filter group ->show/hide filter
then add two new filters  
1)
ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php$xmlhttprequest
2)
/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php$domain=facebook.com
thats all now sender cant able to seen that you read his or her message :)

further more also try this video it has step by step guide to Hide "Seen On" feature of Facebook Messages or chat
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtG75oISKkA
after that you will able to understand how you can read anyone message secretly so that sender cant able to seen that you read his or her message :)

Comment: You are trying to answer a different question. OP asks to explain how, technically, this can be done in an extension - and not how, from a user perspective, set it up using existing extensions.

Comment: i know but this will help OP that how unseen plugins works they are just blocking 2 url just block these 2 url 1)
ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php$xmlhttprequest
2)
/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php$domain=facebook.com
with your code or extension

Comment: It would be great if you could add that to your answer before suggesting adblock.

Comment: ops xan sorry for that now i change 1st paragraph as your suggestion